# Unexplainable pthread mutex deadlock

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, mutex

There seems to be a deadlock in my application caused by a particular mutex. However, the code clearly unlocks the mutex almost immediately after it is locked, and there are no other mutex dependencies between the lock and unlock. The mutex is definitely not locked twice by the same thread.

The issue is occurring with only one (out of many) users of my application. I am working with a core dump generated during the deadlock. The waiting threads are not showing up in the core dump, but the code tells me that none of them have locked the mutex in question. This is the backtrace from the thread that holds the lock:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003aa4e0e054 in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000003aa4e09388 in _L_lock_854 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x0000003aa4e09257 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x000000000043cf59 in my_processor (myvar=0x7fff36ba7430, mystring=0x7fff36ba76c0 
"This is a string")
```

I also printed the data of the mutex in question:

```
(gdb) print my_mutex
$4 = {__data = {__lock = 2, __count = 0, __owner = 0, __nusers = 0, __kind = 2, __spins = 0, __list = {__prev = 0x0, __next = 0x0}},
  __size = "\002", '\000' <repeats 15 times>, "\002", '\000' <repeats 22 times>, __align = 2}
```

This does not seem consistent: the owner is 0, suggesting no thread owns the lock, but yet the thread is blocking waiting for the mutex.

The following snippet shows the declaration and initialization of the mutex:

```
pthread_mutex_t my_mutex;
pthread_mutexattr_t mutex_attr;

/* set up mutex attributes */
pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutex_attr);
pthread_mutexattr_settype(&mutex_attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK);

/* create mutex */
pthread_mutex_init(&my_mutex, &mutex_attr);

/* destroy mutex attributes */
pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mutex_attr);
```

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Is it possible that multiple threads are reaching the mutex_init at the same time creating a weird condition?

Comment: Could you show the relevant parts of the code where you are locking and unlocking mutexes? In what context is the code above called?

Comment: FYI, doing `set print pretty on` in GDB makes it much easier to read struct contents...

Comment: The main thread executes the above snippet calling pthread_mutex_init() before it spawns any other threads.

Comment: *" yet the thread is blocking waiting for the mutex."* What thread? The pasted code, if located in `main()` as stated, is useless in determining your real problem. Its nice to know it was initialized and all, but the key to solving potentially broken locking paradigms is to *see the code that calls for the locks and unlocks.* Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It seems likely that your mutex is being overwritten somewhere by a buffer overflow or dangling pointer write.

Comment: The problem reproduces every time the user restarts the application. Is it likely, or at least plausible, that the behavior would be that consistent with a buffer overflow or dangling pointer overwriting the mutex?

Comment: @user1494899: you may want to use valgrind to help determine if there's a buffer overflow or dangling pointer. And use valgrind's DRD tool which may help determine if there's a problem with the use of the mutex that doesn't involve a memory use bug.

Comment: @user1494899: Certainly, since the inputs to the program when that user logs in are likely very similar or identical.  As Michael Burr suggests, try running the program under valgrind using both the memcheck and helgrind tools.